# Unkown NullPointerException being thrown by the JavaAWT-eventQueue thread

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, awt

This only happens around about 1/10 runs and I'm not exactly sure why it is happening the Exception isn't giving me an error I know

Here is my class that extends JFrame

```
private StyledDocument debug;
    private JScrollPane debugSP;
    private StyledDocument chat;
    private JScrollPane chatSP;

    public DapBotGUI()
    {
        super("JFrame");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);

        JTextPane debug = new JTextPane();

        debugSP = new JScrollPane(debug);
        debugSP.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth() - 20, this.getHeight() / 2 - 20);
        debugSP.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        debugSP.setAutoscrolls(true);

        JTextPane chat = new JTextPane();

        chatSP = new JScrollPane(chat);
        chatSP.setBounds(0, this.getHeight() / 2 - 20, this.getWidth() - 20, this.getHeight() / 2 - 20);
        chatSP.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        chatSP.setAutoscrolls(true);

        this.getContentPane().add(debugSP);
        this.getContentPane().add(chatSP);
        this.setVisible(true);

        this.debug = debug.getStyledDocument();
        this.chat = chat.getStyledDocument();
    }

    public void debug(String message)
    {
        debug(message, Color.BLACK);
    }

    public synchronized void debug(String message, Color color)
    {
        SimpleAttributeSet formatter = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setForeground(formatter, color);
        StyleConstants.setBackground(formatter, Color.WHITE);

        try
        {
            debug.insertString(debug.getLength(), message + System.lineSeparator(), formatter);

            JScrollBar vertical = debugSP.getVerticalScrollBar();
            vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
        }
        catch (BadLocationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void chatMessage(String message)
    {
        chatMessage(message, Color.BLACK);
    }

    public synchronized void chatMessage(String message, Color color)
    {
        SimpleAttributeSet formatter = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setForeground(formatter, color);
        StyleConstants.setBackground(formatter, Color.WHITE);
        try
        {
            chat.insertString(chat.getLength(), message + System.lineSeparator(), formatter);

            JScrollBar vertical = chatSP.getVerticalScrollBar();
            vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
        }
        catch (BadLocationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and then here is the error but from what I can see there are no direct issues with my code causing this error (That I can see).

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.text.FlowView$FlowStrategy.layoutRow(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.FlowView$FlowStrategy.layout(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.FlowView.layout(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.updateChildSizes(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSpanOnAxis(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.layout(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.setSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paintSafely(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.update(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you show the main method? It would be easier if the code was runnable

Comment: the main method is DapBotGui GUI = new DapBotGUI();

Comment: That's not much help, you should figure out when the problem happens, since I dont know your goal and you claim that only 1/10 of the runs throws the error. It's very hard to help you if we can't reproduce the error

Comment: That's what I don't understand there is no particular instance where its thrown and the code above can be ran on its own and it still throws the error in a what seems random instance. just having the JFrame open on the screen throws the error randomly

Comment: Try adding a Java Exception Breakpoint, and run the debugger, when the error occurs, execution will stop and hopefuly you will be directed to the line that caused it. (if using eclipse: Run->Add Java Exception Breakpoint (choose the nullpointer, wich is the one you get, and run the debugger)

Comment: It throws a NPE on FlowView$FlowStrategy.layoutRow(FlowView, int, int) line: not available eclipse won't allow me to debug on the line due to the compiler "not adding line number attributes to generated class file" googled this and went trough the settings to tick this option but its already checked.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).